# Cant remove top space in a div that contains an image

Tags: html, css

I'm programming this gallery. When you click in each thumb it displays an image that is inside a div. I already removed every margin and padding but I can still see a gap at the top of the image.

Here's the code for the gallery when clicked:

```css
ul.thumbs li.content .media { 
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 25px;
    width: 50%;
    min-height: 200px;
}
ul.thumbs li.content .media img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
ul.thumbs li.content {
    width: 100% !important;
    display: none;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    background-color: #fff!important;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0px 0 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="portfolio-content">
    <div id="thumb1">
        <div class="media"><img src="img/thumbs/fc_mock.png" alt="" /> 
        </div>
    <h1 class="display">Branding <br></h1>
    <p class="subtitle">Client: Calíope <br> </p>   
    </div>
    <div id="thumb2">
        <div class="media"><img src="img/thumbs/anatomy_mock.png" alt="" /></div>
        <h1 class="display">Textile <br> Design  <br></h1>
        <p class="subtitle">Client: Calíope <br> </p>
        <a href="https://www.behance.net/gallery/22326815/Caliope" target="_blank" class="btn btn-primary">See full project</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's a screen: 
[image]

Comment: Can you create a fiddle to simulate the issue?

Comment: i think you need to add more code that actually shows the issue... your sample code doesn't look anything like the screenshot

Comment: Can you please create a fiddle or turn this into a code snippet?

Comment: Add `display: block;` for the image.

Comment: idk if this will help, i have the css in different files. This one in the fiddle is just for the gallery. https://jsfiddle.net/randomood/yarwmbww/